CBS350-24XS problem with ip obtain by DHCP pool for IP phones
I have problems with obtaining IP address by DHCP server which configured on CBS350-24XS switch.Problem happens only with IP phones : Cisco SPA504G,Fanvil X3S.

Firmware version is latest : 3.3.0.16
I checked firmware version 3.4.0.17 too and have the same problem with IP obtaining by IP phones.

In this configuration I used the same config which works properly on Cisco sg350 switch and sg300 switch.On this switches configuration for data + voice vlan on one port seems like that and it's work fine,but on this switch it's doesn't work :
switchport mode trunk 
switchport trunk native vlan 10 # data
switchport trunk allowed vlan 20 # voice

I searched through all the forums and the entire Internet, but found nothing useful. I checked 2 more configuration methods. I turned off STP, Smartport, CDP, but this did not help.
I hope you can help me with this problem. This is the first time I have encountered something like this.
Configuration :
config-file-header
sw1
v3.3.0.16 / RCBS3.3_950_377_202
CLI v1.0
file SSD indicator encrypted
@
ssd-control-start
ssd config
ssd file passphrase control unrestricted
no ssd file integrity control
ssd-control-end cb0a3fdb1f3a1af4e4430033719968c0
!
!
unit-type-control-start
unit-type unit 1 network te uplink none
unit-type unit 2 network te uplink none
unit-type unit 3 network te uplink none
unit-type unit 4 network te uplink none
unit-type-control-end
!
cdp pdu flooding
cdp mandatory-tlvs validation
spanning-tree loopback-guard
vlan database
vlan 10,20
exit
voice vlan id 20
voice vlan state auto-enabled
voice vlan cos 5
voice vlan oui-table add 0001e3 Siemens_AG_phone
voice vlan oui-table add 00036b Cisco_phone
voice vlan oui-table add 00096e Avaya
voice vlan oui-table add 000fe2 H3C_Aolynk
voice vlan oui-table add 0060b9 Philips_and_NEC_AG_phone
voice vlan oui-table add 00d01e Pingtel_phone
voice vlan oui-table add 00e075 Polycom/Veritel_phone
voice vlan oui-table add 00e0bb 3Com_phone
voice vlan oui-table add 0c383e Fanvil
arp timeout 60000
ip dhcp server
ip dhcp pool network USERS
address low 192.168.10.10 high 192.168.10.50 255.255.255.0
lease infinite
default-router 192.168.10.254
exit
ip dhcp pool network VOICE
address low 192.168.20.10 high 192.168.20.20 255.255.255.0
lease infinite
default-router 192.168.20.254
exit
bonjour interface range vlan 1
hostname sw1
line console
exec-timeout 0
exit
line ssh
exec-timeout 0
exit
line telnet
exec-timeout 0
exit
line console
no autobaud
exit
line console
speed 19200
exit
username admin password encrypted $15$suUskbfzIaJ/LQlN$Hj/kux7Kn9CODEIMCxj9hNuSikaqBoN5Lj4HJTTork42OwA8TlfNsktedi8pPR94HOhvT8y6miDu8aIat8qMXQ== privilege 15
ip ssh server
ip http timeout-policy 0
clock timezone AZ 4
no clock source sntp
clock source browser
!
interface vlan 1
 ip address 192.168.1.254 255.255.255.0
 no ip address dhcp
!
interface vlan 10
 name Users
 ip address 192.168.10.254 255.255.255.0
!
interface vlan 20
 name voice
 ip address 192.168.20.254 255.255.255.0
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/0/3
 switchport access vlan 10
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/0/4
 switchport access vlan 10
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/0/5
 switchport access vlan 10
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/0/6
 switchport access vlan 20
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/0/7
 switchport access vlan 20
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/0/8
 switchport access vlan 20
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/0/9
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport trunk native vlan 10
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/0/10
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport trunk native vlan 10 # data vlan
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 20 # voice vlan
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/0/11
 flowcontrol on
 storm-control broadcast level 10
 storm-control multicast level 10
 switchport mode general
 switchport general allowed vlan add 20 tagged
 switchport general allowed vlan add 10 untagged
 switchport general pvid 10
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/0/12
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport trunk native vlan 10
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 20
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/0/13
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree guard root
 switchport access vlan 20
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 20
!
interface oob
 ip address dhcp
!
exit
macro auto enabled


